# Delete cloudblockblob with all subdirectories in it

Tags: c#, winforms, azure

I'm on a project where I need the function to delete a cloudblockblob in my Azure storage.
I allready have my cloudblockblob, but I don't know how to delete the cloudblockblob with all his subdirectories and blobs.

This is what I've tried:

```
blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();
```

But I don't think it works...

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? Are you looking for the functionality to delete one or more blobs in a subdirectory?

Comment: I don't get an exception, but nothing happens.. And I'm looking indeed for the functionality to delete one or more blobs in a subdirectory + the subdirectory hisself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm it's fixed, I had to loop through all items in the subdirectory and than delete the subdirectory itself.. It's solved! Thanks for viewing this question..

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all sub containers and delete them, which deletes any children that are blobs not children that are containers.